# Short proofs about integrability

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

If true, the prove it; if false, the provide a counterexample.

a) If $f$ is integrable, but $g$ isn't, then $f + g$ is not integrable.
True: Assume that $f + g$ is integrable, then $f$ and $g$ must be integrable. Contradiction.

b) If $f$ is nonnegative and is integrable on $[a, b]$, and $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = 0$, then $f(x) = 0, \forall x \in [a, b]$
False: take $f(x) = |x|$ on $[-2, 2]$

Are the above proofs ok?

Comment: The integral of $f(x) = |x|$ on $[-2,2]$ is $4$, not $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these proofs work. For the first one, recall that $f$ is integrable if and only if $-f$ is, and then use your thing about a sum of integrables being integrable on $(f+g)+(-f)$.

For the second, that function doesn't work (and nor does any continuous function, since if $f$ is continuous you can find an $\epsilon$ such that $f>\epsilon$ on some interval of width at least $\delta$, and hence, since integration is linear, the integral is no smaller than $\epsilon \delta >0$. Think of what you know about the upper and lower sums (or the Lebesgue measure of, since you don't specify) the characteristic function of a single point (i.e. a function that is zero everywhere but $0$, say).

Answer (score 0):

By contradiction. Suppose that f is integrable, g is not integrable and f+g is integrable.

Then as f+g is integrable we have $\int_a^bf+g=\int_a^bf+\int_a^bg$ so $\int_a^bg=\int_a^bf+g-\int_a^bf$, i.e., g is integrable and that is false.